# after jquery ajax sucess $(this) not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, this, innerhtml

I am new to js and jquery please help me with this,
problem is:

```
$(this).html('<span class="label label-success icon-fontawesome-webfont-11"> Paid</span>');
```

is not working.

```
window.onload = function() {
    $(".myclass").click(function(){
        var current_id = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/ajax.php",
                data:'current_id='+ current_id
           }).done(function(result) {
                $(this).html('<span class="label label-success icon-fontawesome-webfont-11"> Paid</span>');
          });
    });
}
```

Comment: pls format your code..!

Comment: when you click just check is there any error in retrieving data? see errors in inspect elements

Comment: no errors in retriving data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), like:

```
window.onload = function() {
    $(".myclass").click(function(){
        var current_id = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                context: this, //add this
                url: "/ajax.php",
                data:{current_id : current_id},
           }).done(function(result) {
                $(this).html('<span class="label label-success icon-fontawesome-webfont-11"> Paid</span>');
          });
    });
}
```

Comment: could you please explain me why context is needed in this particular code

Comment: @alagu It isn't, if you keep the context yourself.  jQuery redefines what `this` when calling your handlers.

Comment: this in dont context is an object that represents the ajax settings, so using context: this, will make context as your dom object, pls see the doc linked in answer

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$.proxy` to fix it.

```
$(".myclass").click(function(){

    var current_id = this.id;
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "/ajax.php",

            data:'current_id='+ current_id

       }).done($.proxy(function(result) {
            $(this).html('<span class="label label-success icon-fontawesome-webfont-11"> Paid</span>');
      }, this));  

});
```

Comment: Cool, I haven't seen that before!  Very handy.

Answer (score 1):

The context of `this` changes.  In this case, `this` context is bound to the result of the Deferred `done` handler.  In your click function store the value of `this` in a variable.  Then, access it later.

```
$(".myclass").click(function(){
    var current_id = this.id;
    var $clicked = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax.php",
        data:'current_id='+ current_id
    ).done(function(result) {
        $clicked.html('<span class="label label-success icon-fontawesome-webfont-11"> Paid</span>');
    });
});
```

Also, I don't know why you are specifying your data the way you are, but consider just using an object, and let jQuery do the work.  `data: {current_id: current_id}`.  Otherwise, you will have to encode the values yourself.

Comment: thanks, response i just googled it and using in my code still facing the problem

Comment: then how to send , multiple data @brad

Comment: @alagu Just add to the object `{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}`.  I recommend reading up on JavaScript before continuing.  Object literals are a key part of the syntax.